# Asterisk (raspbx): py script - open asterisk CLI and fire command

Tags: python, sms, asterisk, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send SMS from a python script over asterisk to my Smarphone.
I've installed RasPBX on a Raspberry 3 with chan_dongle.

Manually it works fine:

```
asterisk -vvvr
```

and then

```
dongle sms dongle0 +4178xxxxxxx Hello, nice weather today
```

My idea was to write a python script to open the asterisk cli and type in the command to send the sms.

like this:

```
import os
import time

os.system("asterisk -vvvr")
time.sleep(2)
os.system("dongle sms dongle0 +4178xxxxxxx Hello, nice weather today")
```

but it didn't work! can anyone help me?

thank you. greetings from switzerland (where the weather isn't nice today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
asterisk -rx "core show channels"
```

> -x command
>                 Connect to a running Asterisk process and execute a command on a command line, passing any output through to stan‐
>                 dard out and then terminating when the command execution completes. Implies -r when -R is not explicitly supplied.